# Is there an easy way to embed a static HTML file into a Hamlet template in Yesod

Tags: html, templates, yesod, hamlet

There are many cases when I have a lot of HTML that I just want to embed in my Hamlet templates as is, without explicitly converting it to Hamlet.

I haven't really found a nice way of doing this, since if I use `readFile` in `defaultLayout` where the wrapper template is being constructed (or in any other place), I'd need to specify a path to the file, which means I need to have the file available when I deploy my application.

What I'm looking for is something similar to the way static assets are handler, where I get a function, such as `css_bootstrap_css`, that I can use to link to the asset, and have it built together with the application.

Comment: You can't get a function like `css_bootstrap_css` unless the files exist at compile time. If they do, and are under static, you're already getting them. If the files aren't known at compile or deploy time, where do they come from and how is there a requirement to embed them in the default layout if their existence is dynamic in some way?

Comment: @pbrisbin sorry for not being clearer. I do want to embed them and I do have them present at compile time. I can see how to use `StaticR (StaticRoute ["html", "something.html"] [])` to get the path, but how do I actually embed that in the template?

Comment: Ah I was mistaken. I think the generated functions are just Routes to them, not a handle to read the content. I don't think there's a way to embed content by name in a hamlet template. You'll need to read the file then put something like `#{preEscapedHtml theContent}` in the template.